# Unable to access Kubernetes Dashboard from Azure Cloud Shell

Tags: azure, azure-aks, azure-cloud-shell

I am using Azure DevOps Pipelines to deploy microservices in AKS. Once deployed in a Kubernetes cluster, I used to browse the Kubernetes dashboard using below commands in Azure Cloud Shell.

az aks get-credentials --resource-group ResourceGroupName --name ClusterName

az aks browse --resource-group ResourceGroupName --name ClusterName

I will get a URL to access the console once I run these commands.
https://gateway12.centralindia.console.azure.com/n/cc-a0c05198/cc-a0c05198/proxy/8001/

But now I am getting below screen when I navigate to the above link.
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: have you deleted any deployments specific to dashboard?

see the diff between a new cluster and existing one using the command `kubectl get deployment --all-namespaces`

Comment: Can't it solve your problem? I didn't see any responses you give.

Answer (score 0):

I think when browses the AKS in the operating system that only has the command line, without a desktop, the command `az aks browse` choose to create a proxy, not the dashboard for you. Here is the screenshot that when you execute the CLI `az aks browse` in the cloud shell:

[image]

When you execute in the operating system that has a desktop, the CLI chooses to port forward the dashboard pod for you. Here is the screenshot:

[image]

You can also port forward the dashboard pod in the cloud shell, but cloud shell does not have the desktop, so you can only use the command `curl` to access the URL, it just shows this:

[image]

And you can also create a proxy in the operating system that has a desktop, it will show you the same as you provided in the question. So I recommend you execute the CLI `az aks browse` in the operating system that has a desktop, not the cloud shell.